# Python の subprocess で複数のパラメータを渡してプログラムを起動した時、意図した通り動作しない

Tags: python, windows, 文字コード

環境は Windows 10, Python 3.6.5 です。
コマンドプロンプト上で実行に成功したものをPython上で実行しようと考えています(今後の追加ファイルのため)

```
soffice --headless --convert-to ods --infilter="Lotus:60" ./123/test.123
```

sofficeコマンドにより `.123` ファイルを `.ods` ファイルに変換するコマンドです。
`infilter="Lotus:60"` により、日本語を入力として受け取り、拡張子がodsに変換されファイル出力されます。

ここまでの動作確認は出来ており、日本語でファイルも出力されてます。

このコマンドをPython上で実行しようとしたコードがこちらになります。

```
import subprocess

path_to_soffice = 'C:/Program Files/LibreOffice/program/soffice'#sofficeのpath
subprocess.run([path_to_soffice,'--headless','--convert-to','ods','--infilter="Lotus:60"','./123/test.123'], check=True)
```

実行自体はうまく行くのですが、infilterが上手く動いていない様で、sofficeのデフォルト言語(恐らくイタリア語?)でファイルが出力されます。

Answer (score 0):

どうもパラメータをリストで指定すると、`"`が`\"`に変換されるようです。

`--infilter="Lotus:60"`と指定したい所が`--infilter=\"Lotus:60\"`となってしまうので、有効なパラメータとみなされなくなってしまうのではないでしょうか？

特に不具合が無ければ、`subprocess.run()`の最初のパラメータを以下のように1つの文字列にまとめてみてはどうでしょう？

```
subprocess.run('"C:/Program Files/LibreOffice/program/soffice" --headless --convert-to ods --infilter="Lotus:60" ./123/test.123', check=True)
```

Comment: 実行うまく行きました。データ整形の前段階で躓いていたのでとても助かりました！ありがとうございます。